# Performance testing for WPF application in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, testing, load-testing, performance-testing

I have WPF application. The application is handling reading input files and writing multiple output files. Internally it is grouping the input file records and writing them as output file based on each group.

Now I want to do the performance testing of this particular application. How the input reading and output writing is doing for smaller group file and larger group file

Is there any .Net tool or API to perform this operaiton. I just need to do see the total time, memory consumption  , CPU time taken for each file processing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856837/c-sharp-wpf-testing-strategies

Comment: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Which-is-best-automation-tool-86204.S.131775208

Comment: If you're using the Ultimate version of Visual Studio, you can use the integrated .NET profiler to test the performance of the application. Take a look at this: [Testing Performance and Stress Using Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540.aspx)